Diffusion of Electrons/Quasiparticles
I want to simulate the diffusion of electrons, or, more accurately, I want to simulate the diffusion of Bogoliubov quasiparticles. So I will break up some region of space into a fine grid and apply a numerical discrete approximation for the diffusion equation.
I am wondering though if this is physically reasonable. What is the size limit of a cell size before it is no longer valid to treat the quasiparticles as point particles localized within a cell? I am not sure if the de Broglie wavelength is appropriate to use here; furthermore, if it was, it is not clear how to estimate the momentum of the quasiparticles because diffusion will approach some steady state of very low momentum.
